# Move those files that contain the string to directory with Bash

Tags: bash, grep

Create a script, that will take 2 arguments:

```
3.sh <directory> <destination>
```

Search the files in `<directory>` for substring “**moveme**” in the file content.

Move those files that contain the string to directory `<destination>`

**My Bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Retry..."
else
    if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
        echo "Retry ..."
    else
        echo "Try to fiend in folder {$1} files with this content {123} "
        grep -l "123" $1/*
        #grep -c "123" $1/*
    fi
fi
```

How to transfer finded file from one directory to other?

Comment: `mv $directory/$file $destination/$file` ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but which concretely file?

Comment: $file -> how to write in this variable gotten resoult from grep

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a while loop set a variable that contains the grep, while it exists, and if it is a file, move it to the new directory..

Comment: yea, on theory i understand how to make it, but in practic? .. :(

Comment: something like `found=$(grep "$123" $directory) if [ -f $found ] { do something}`

Comment: Not asked, but an improvement to the script:

#/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: script SOURCEDIR DESTDIR";
    exit 1
fi

(A much cleaner way of checking if the script was called with two parameters).

Answer (score 0):

```
str="moveme"
find "$1"/* -prune -type f -exec grep -l "$str" "{}" \; | xargs -i echo mv -i "{}" "$2"/
```

Actually, to check no. of arguments, checking $2 is enough

```
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
        echo "Retry ..."
```

More importantly, you should handle the possible overwrites to the files in $2.

Comment: When piping from `find` to `xargs`, use `find … -print0 | xargs -0`

Comment: Thanks. Just learned how to avoid the possible \n in a filename from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will return a list of files. You need to execute `mv` over each of the files.

You can use `xargs` as suggested in another answer, but I prefer this on-liner:

```
for file in $(grep -l "123" $1/*); do mv $file $2; done
```

It iterates over the list of files returned by `grep` and moves them one by one.

You may need to add some error checking, so here is a more readable version:

```
for file in $(grep -l "123" $1/*); do
    mv $file $2;
done
```

Also, I find it's usually a good idea to change the IFS variable before this kind of loop

```
export IFS=$'\n'
```

That way, you will avoid a lot of problems with files having whitespace in the name (unless they have a newline character embedded).

Comment: Note that for <n> files and <m> matching files, the xargs method calls `grep` <n> times and `mv` <m> times. The for loop calls `grep` only once.

Comment: Changing the IFS isn't encouraged just to fix a command that breaks on whitespace. If you want to iterate over files, it's better to use `find` and its `-exec` capabilities. Also, you should double-quote your variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Retry... ./3.sh {folder_from}/ {text} {folder_to}/"
else
    if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
        echo "Retry ... ./3.sh {folder_from}/ {text} {folder_to}/"
    else
        echo "Try to find in folder {$1} files with this content {123} "
        cd ~/tasks/$1
        grep -l "123" * > list.txt
        while read line
        do
            name=$line
            mv $line  ~/tasks/$3/$line
        done < list.txt
        #grep -c "123" $1\/*
        rm list.txt
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting solutions to this problem.  This one is a one-liner, and while it will generate a few errors for directories (grep won't be able to search them for your search text), it should nail your task.

```
grep -l --null 'moveme' "${1}"/* | xargs -0 mv --target-directory="${2}"
```

If you want it to be a recursive search of the source directory, a better solution is:

```
grep -l --recursive --null 'moveme' "${1}" | xargs -0 mv --target-directory="${2}"
```

Both of these assume a quality implementation of grep, xargs and mv, but we've had options like this in Linux for ages now.

I haven't tested this syntax, but the premise is:

Grep the files listed in  for 'moveme', and output just the filenames (-l) of the matching files, separated by a null character (--null).

The output of this process goes into xargs, which with the -0 argument knows to use the null character as a separator, and pass the listed files to the mv command as arguments.

The last part of this is the --target-directory argument which is key for using mv with xargs; it lets you put the destination for the move before all of the arguments.

Best of luck.